# FileSystem Is Not Responding After Login Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, 23.04

I have been receiving this error message since upgrading to Kubuntu 23.04:

[image: FileSystem Error Message]

The error message only appears after I login into my username. I have latte app layout as my desktop theme.